# Get http context username with REST on intranet

Tags: javascript, rest, http, httpcontext, intranet

I'm building a web app on my companies intranet, and I just want to get the username of the logged on user when they land at the site.

I really don't know what other information to provide other than we use microsoft and it's a large company so azure and all that goodness is used. Also, I'm not an IT person so I don't have access to our Azure dashboard but it's my understanding that I don't need that to just get the username?

I could be asking the wrong question here so feel free to give me some guidance, I'm trying to get a better understanding of how this works. Sending any additional resources is definitely welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: The keywords here is "integrated authentication" in IIS.  You didn't specify which technology you indend to use for the REST backend service.  I'm guessing .NET Web API?  This might help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-windows-authentication-in-web-api-and-angular-app/

Comment: @HaukurHaf I'm the front-end guy, using React, etc. I was expecting to get username when user comes to site and send to our server using rest. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You cannot retrieve the username on the front-end.  When the backend is correctly configured to use integrated authentication, the username can be retrieved on the backend, in the server-side code.  This is not necessarily a trivial task.

Comment: @HaukurHaf he is using Python w/ Flask, do you know of any resources that would be good for me to share with him on this topic?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that stack, at least not enough to be of help.  I doubt that it will work, but I might be wrong.  If it's hosted on IIS, there might be a chance.  Any other web server and you are probably out of luck.